# RTC plugin for jenkins how to build from RTC stream?

Tags: jenkins, rtc

I have several jobs building from RTC streams using RTC SCM plugin for Jenkins, but every time I build from a stream it creates a snapshot ON THAT STREAM with just the build number from Jenkins as the name, so if I run 2 Jenkins jobs which build off the same stream, you eventually run into RTC complaining about snapshot build number not being created because it already exists and the build fails. So I either need to delete the snapshot from RTC stream, but "this is not advisable" (coming from lame IBM documentation) as it puts the repository into an "unstable" state (and indeed causes moot "database in incorrect state _UUID missing, etc" errors on subsequent builds from the stream), but then if I don't do this, the only other solution is to have only one build job off the stream or use a workspace, which is somewhat an annoyance to create/maintain for every stream.

Best solution I can think of is use the build name from jenkins + build number when creating the snapshot, at least that adds some degree of uniqueness. Can anyone suggest a workaround for this "feature" that doesn't involve hacky cml arguments to the build kit or similar nonsense? I need to be able to control snapshot names in the plugin, otherwise "build from stream" option is more or less useless.